# Select the value for each first day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below table

[image]

I want to select the value of `[UsedSpace(MB)]` for each first day of the month.
For example `1/5/2015` the value of `[UsedSpace(MB)]` should be `10`.

I tried the below query, but without success.

```
Select Cast(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,ExecuteTime),0) AS DATE) AS [Monthly],
       [UsedSpace(MB)]
from tbl_Test
group by DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,ExecuteTime),0), [UsedSpace(MB)]
Order by DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,ExecuteTime),0)
```

Please any suggestions.

Comment: That seems overloy complicated. Why not just use `WHERE DATEPART(d,ExecuteTime) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample data provided, you can simply make a where clause for the first day of the month. If you need a more generic solution, you need to get the lowest date for each month, and then join this with the original table.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT MIN(ExecuteTime) AS Monthly
  FROM tbl_Test
  GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, ExecuteTime), 0)
)
SELECT t.ExecuteTime, t.[UsedSpace(MB)]
FROM tbl_Test AS t
JOIN cte AS m
ON t.ExecuteTime = m.Monthly
ORDER BY t.ExecuteTime
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that you will always have a single record for each date then you could limit the results in the WHERE statement. If there may be multiple records on the same date or no record on a date then you should use a MIN function.

```
SELECT
    CAST(ExecuteTime as Date) AS Date, 
    UsedSpace
FROM tbl_Test
WHERE Day(ExecuteTime) = 1
```